# Moderating ROS-Users

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has there been any thought put into moderating ROS-Users such that emails that would get the reply "Try ROS Answers" don't have to go to everyone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32233/moderating-ros-users/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has not been discussed.  The volume is much lower than previously encountered.  And the effort required to moderate a list is significant.  Until we get a significant demand for it we probably won't change the way the list operates.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-04-23**:
Are you saying that my demands aren't significant?! :-D